# How to analyse the stability of hyperbolic balance laws with diffusion?

Tags: stability, hyperbolic-pde

Assume we have the following system of balance laws:
$$ U_t+\partial_x F(U,x)=S(U,x)+\partial_x(D(U,x)U_x). $$

Is there any method to analyse the stability of its solution (assume that the solution exists)? Here the dependence on $x$ is crucial, otherwise one at least could do the Fourier analysis after linearisation. It is really appreciated if one even can introduce a related paper.

Thanks!